# how to make custom validation using 3 or more parameter with Db name in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5

I can make and use rule for verified in laravel 5.5+ but I need to verified with more parameter other than $attribute, $value, $id that is $flag, another attribute and even Db itself, like validation unique but a little more different

I already search in internet and none have done it

```
public function __construct($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $modal = ledger::where('id', $this->id)->first();

    $ledger = ledger::where('id','!=', $modal->id )->where(['fk_id'=>"$modal->fk_id", 'flag'=>'1', $attribute=>$value])->first();

    if($ledger == 'null')
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want that Db_name, flag value, and attribute fk_id is replaceable by input.

Answer (score 1):

I have already my answer

in my controller I use this

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
    $this->validate($request, [
       'mssl_kode' => [new msslRules($id, 'ledger', 'id', 'fk_id', 'flag')],
    ]);

    //others script
}
```

then in my rules I use this

```
public function __construct($id, $db, $id2, $fkid, $flag)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->db = "\\App\\".$db;
    $this->id2 = $id2;
    $this->fkid = $fkid;
    $this->flag = $flag;
}

public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $id2 = $this->id2;
    $fkid = $this->fkid;

    $modal = $this->db::where($id2, $this->id)->first();

    $ledger = $this->db::where($id2,'!=', $modal->$id2 )->where([$fkid=>$modal->$fkid, $this->flag=>'1', $attribute=>$value])->first();

    if($ledger == null)
    {
        return true;
    }else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps for the others